# str_replace doesn't seems to work with the implode function

Tags: php

After imploding an array:

```
$in_list = "'".implode("','",$array)."'";
```

`$in_list` content is :

```
'Robert','Emmanuel','José','Alexander'
```

Now when i try to replace the word `José` by another string,

```
    str_replace("José","J",$in_list);
```

It doesn't get the new value, `José` is still there. Am i missing something? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 7):

How exactly do you try to replace the string?
When trying it this way:

```
$in_list = str_replace("José","J",$in_list);

echo $in_list;
```

everything should work fine.

Remember, the function is returning a value. So it returns a new string.

Comment: I did this exactly, the accented word aren't replaced, however, i try it with a normal word(without accent) and it works.

Comment: Try the following: echo ord("é"); If the value is 233, you use the same character as I use. Maybe you have got a different ascii value?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It depends on your array.

```
$str = array('Robert','Emmanuel','José','Alexander');
$str = implode(",", $str);
print str_replace('José', 'J', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on, It seems to work for me. What version of PHP are you using?

```
$in_list = "'".implode("','", array('Robert', 'Emmanuel', 'José', 'Alexander'))."'";
$replaced = str_replace("José", "J", $in_list);

//prints 'Robert','Emmanuel','J','Alexander'
echo $replaced;
```

See: http://codepad.viper-7.com/24qutm

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, but it doesn't look like I'm doing anything notably different from you?

```
$array = array('Robert', 'Emmanuel', 'José', 'Alexander');
$in_list = "'".implode("','",$array)."'";

echo $in_list.PHP_EOL;
echo str_replace("José","J",$in_list).PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:**

```
'Robert','Emmanuel','José','Alexander'
'Robert','Emmanuel','J','Alexander'
```

Keep in mind that `str_replace` will not perform the replacement on `$in_list` itself, but rather return a string containing the replacement.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

try `$in_list = html_entity_decode((str_replace(htmlentities("José"),"J",htmlentities($in_list));`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried on a word without accents? I would say you have a character set mismatch, for example 'José' in $in_list is in latin1 character set and your PHP source file in UTF8.

If this is the case, you should first convert either your PHP file or the variable to the character set you want to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Spontaneous guess: Those two strings are not the same. I suppose one "José" is a string hardcoded in your source code and the other is received from the database or the browser or so. If the encoding of the two strings is not the same, PHP won't identify them as identical and not replace the character. Make sure your source code file is saved in the same encoding as the data you're working on, preferably both being UTF-8.